# Build font file within monaco-editor package with webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, webpack-4, monaco-editor

I am trying to integrate a package into our project that depends upon the [`monaco-editor`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monaco-editor) module.

Some details on our project:

- Ejected from the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) project
- Language: Typescript (v3.9)
- Build system: Webpack (v4.44)
- Monaco Editor (v0.22.3)

Here's what the dependency of our project looks like:

```
Project A
   |--> EditorPackage
            |--> MonacoEditor (v0.22.3)
```

We also rely on the Monaco-editor [webpack plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin) to register specific languages and configure web workers correctly in our project. When I try to build our project with webpack, I suddenly started seeing this error:

[image]

The `.ttf` is a font file packaged within the monaco-editor sources and I found a relevant [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin/issues/90) for this. I followed the guidance in the [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/docs/integrate-esm.md#option-1-using-the-monaco-editor-loader-plugin) to add rules for packaging up `.ttf` files correctly by modifying our webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.ttf$/,
  loader: require.resolve("file-loader")
}
```

I also tried adding `.ttf` to the `extensions` configuration for webpack. I still seem to be hitting the same error. I think this might be due to our indirect dependency on MonacoEditor through the `EditorPackage` as I highlighted above.

Any ideas on how to parse and resolve the `.ttf` file correctly here?

Answer (score 1):

The error that I saw was getting emitted from the `file-loader` plugin. With the webpack 4 upgrade, there were some breaking changes for loaders highlighted in the [Incompatible Loaders](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6064#issue-279132001) section of this [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6064).

Following the discussion in that issue, there are 2 solutions for the issue:

1. Workaround - Add a `context` option to the `file-loader` plugin in your webpack config:

```
const fileLoader = {
  loader: require.resolve("file-loader"),
  //... other config
  options: {
    context: process.cwd() // this fixes the error
  }
};
```

2. Upgrade `file-loader` to a v 1.1.6 or later.
   References: [changelog](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#116-2017-12-16), file-loader [issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/233)

Hope that helps any one else facing a similar issue.